# How to write LINQ in C# with joins based on SQL Query?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to write a linq based on the following query.

IN SQL Server,

```
select EXID,ID,NAME 
from Table1 A
join Table2 B on A.BXID = B.BID
left outer join Table3 C ON C.AXID = A.ID
AND C.EXID = (some number/NULL)
```

This gives me 300 records

In LINQ,

```
try
        {
            using (var context = new cltransformationContext())
            {
                var Details = (
                            from A in context.Table1
                            join B in context.Table2 on A.BXID equals B.BID
                            join C in context.Table3 on A.ID equals C.AXID  
                select new Table1()
                           {
                            ID = A.ID,
                            name = A.NAME + '-' B.Name
                            }).ToList();
                return Details;
            }
        }
```

I am getting 5000 records here.

I have missed **left outer join** and  **C.EXID = (some number/NULL)** condition.
How to do that in the query?

I should only get the 300 records.

Comment: You are missing the AND.

Comment: Not able to do that in c#. How do we add that condition?

Comment: join C in context.Table3.Where(x => x.EXID == 123)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will create LEFT JOIN:

```cs
var query =
    from A in context.Table1
    join B in context.Table2 on A.BXID equals B.BID
    from C in context.Table3.Where(C => A.ID == C.AXID && C.EXID == ...).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new Table1
    {
        ID = A.ID,
        name = A.NAME + '-' B.Name
    };
```

Comment: Getting few errors - Invalid expression term 'select', Expected contextual keyword 'on' , Expected contextual keyword 'equals'

Comment: I have replaced `join` with `from`. Probably you have missed that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
var query =
    from A in context.Table1
    join B in context.Table2 on A.BXID equals B.BID
    join table3 in context.Table3.Where(X => x.EXID = 123) on A.ID == table3.AXID into table3Joined
    from C in table3Joined.DefaultIfEmpty() // this is how we do the left join
    select new Table1
    {
        ID = A.ID,
        name = A.NAME + '-' B.Name
    };
```

The complexity lies in the fact that we have to place the join into `table3Joined` and then we can do `from C in table3Joined.DefaultIfEmpty()`